# Reducing 3v supply to run 2.4v laser diode

Tags: resistors, dc, voltage-divider, laser-diode

I am setting up a laser trip wire system, this question revolves solely around the laser itself.

IMPORTANT: The laser is always on (it will have an on/off switch)

Supply voltage is 3v (2x aa's)

Laser specs are:
Operating voltage - 2.4v
Reverse voltage - 2.3v
Threshold current - 24mA
Operating current - 40mA
Optical power - 10mW

The guy in the shop said 3v would be fine to run the diode, then upon testing he destroyed it, so it's obviously not.

A bit of research has found two main points, 1. You can reduce voltage with a resistor(s), and 2. You can't reduce voltage with a resistor(s).

I found a site which explains how to select two resistors to drop the voltage, but it's not 100% clear as the value of R2 is dependant on knowing the value of R1. This seems to follow a basic 1:4 ratio, i.e. 1k/4k, 10k/40k etc. for the circuit I am using but I need to know what value(s) to use.

Alternatively, a cheap, small, simple method of doing it better is also welcome, but I'd definitely like to understand how to do it with 2 resistors. Being such a small amperage I'm guessing the 2 resistor method won't suffer heat issues etc. like a larger load would do?

Comment: Before you build it, do you realize that a 10 mW laser can be dangerous. What are your safety regulations for using those? If someoene looks at the beam and gets eye damage, you are responsible for building it.

Comment: I wonder which laser diode comes without a built-in photo diode for the servo circuit. At most, a 10mW one which is totally able to burn its own mirrors.

Answer (score 4):

First, the goal is not to reduce the voltage for the laser diode (just like an LED). The diode itself will determine the forward voltage drop across it (2.4Vin this case). This is not a choice. you don't get to choose to run the diode at a higher or lower voltage. The diode will do whatever it can to make the voltage across it 2.4V when you apply a voltage at >2.4V across it. This includes drawing thousands of amps such that the power supply sags down to 2.4V (if the diode doesn't explode first).

Therefore, the goal is not to reduce the voltage for the diode. The diode does this on its own. Instead, the goal to limit the current through the diode so that the diode doesn't explode from overcurrent when the diode forces this voltage across itself.

As for the "two resistor method", I have no idea what you are talking about. Maybe you are talking about a resistive voltage divider? In which case that will NOT work because the resistive divider assumes the load is "infinite" impedance which a laser diode is definitely not. In other words, a resistive divider reduces a voltage and expects to provide ZERO current. A laser diode definitely requires something other than zero current. Trying to power a laser diode off a resistive divider will cause a severe voltage sag on the output due to the current resulting in a circuit that doesn't work (unless your chosen resistances are so low that the resistors are running red hot and wasting more power than the laser diode is actually using).

### Current Source:

You can wire up an LM317 (the battery is the load, so in this case that is the laser diode):

[image]

From LM317 datasheet.

### Current Limiting-Resistor:

Instead, you can just use one resistor. The same way you would size a resistor and known voltage to provide current to an LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2febWj6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Between the resistor and diode, they must drop the entire voltage of the supply. Since the diode's voltage drop is fixed, then that means the remainder of the supply must drop across the resistor. Since the current flowing through the resistor must be the same as the current flowing through the diode, if you size the resistor so that a particular current flows through it when this remainder voltage appears across it, then this is also the diode's current.

\$ V_{supply} = V_{diode} + V_{resistor} = V_{supply} = V_{diode} + (R \times I) \$

Comment: It will be 33 \$ \Omega\$ resistor for 36 mA for the LM317 constant current supply, which is just below specified 40 mA operating current. This is safest.

Comment: Would this do the trick? Could you explain a little further the connection, your diagram has a resistor after the lm317 yes? https://www.jaycar.com.au/lm317t-1-2-37v-1-5a-adjustable-voltage-regulator/p/ZV1615

Comment: The LM317 won't work properly when supplied from 2 AA batteries.  It requires the input voltage to be 3V higher than the output voltage.  The 2 AA batteries in series provide just about 3V, so it will not work.  You need at least 5.4V (head room for the LM317 plus the laser forward voltage.)  So, 4 AA batteries in  series and the LM317 as a current regulator would work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can go 6v no worries at all, but do I need a resistor as in DKNguyen's 1st diagram?

Comment: @mrkd1991 A LM317 to supply 40mA is like over the top overkill. Save it for when you really need it, like an adjustable voltage power supply up to 1 Amp.

Comment: @Indraneel your first comment supports the lm317, your second doesn't. I got the lm317 for free (new), but what would your suggestion be?

Comment: @mrkd1991 Of course you can use the LM317 if you want. It's only that it's overkill, requires higher voltage, significantly more expensive, bulky, and could be better used elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for the graphic introduction.

Comment: @Janka here is the graphic to go along with it https://youtu.be/FyzE9thQIPo?t=120  Laser drawing millions of amps.

Comment: @mrkd1991 The LM317 adjusts the OUTPUT and ADJUST pin to have a difference of 1.25V. If you stick a resistor in between them that it adjusts the current to be I = 1.25/R. That's how it works as a constant current source.

Answer (score 1):

A simple constant current source can be made with a few components, to ensure long working life for the laser.

[image]

The red LED (not the laser) has a constant voltage drop of about 1.4V and serves as a voltage reference for the resistor R1 which sets the current. Alternately a pair of 1N4148 can also be used in series. The base-emitter drop of 0.7V is subtracted from this reference voltage. The resulting 0.7V/Rset is the constant current allowed by the transistor. Connect the laser instead of the example 1\$\Omega\$ load.

> 1.4V - 0.7V = 0.7V
>
> 0.7V / 18 \$\Omega\$ = 38 mA

The transistor can be replaced with any cheap NPN transistor of your choice. Circuit will work at 3V (Rset = 12\$\Omega\$ for 40mA load current, 18\$\Omega\$ for 28mA). At low currents, the voltage drop across the LED will marginally decrease. The correct resistor can be set by measuring the voltage across emitter and ground.

Also keep in mind that the 3.3V laser "module" might already have a 33\$\Omega\$ resistor in it. In that case, you will need at least 4V for this circuit.